# moving window supremum of a Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $W$ be a  Wiener process.

For each fixed $t>\frac12$, is it true that,$$\sup_{s\in[0,\frac12]}|W(t-s)|$$ has the same law as $$\sup_{s\in[0,\frac12]}|W(t)-W(s)| ?$$

Comment: Yes. What do you know about the process $W$?

Comment: $W$ is 1-dimensional Brownian motion starting at $0$. Could you please justify why it is true?

Comment: What. Do. You. Know. About. W?

Comment: @Did I'm not able to understand your question. What additional information is required?  I know that for each fixed $s$ and $t$, $W(t-s)$ is of the same law as $W(t)-W(s)$. But the question I ask requires considering $W$ sample path values at all $s\in [0,\frac12]$.

Comment: Got it. Define $\hat{W}(v)=W(s+v)-W(v)$. Then $\hat{W}$ is a BM starting at $0$. And $W(t)-W(s)=\int_0^{t-s}dW(s+v)=\int_0^{t-s}d\hat{W}(v)=\hat{W}(t-s)$.

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $